# Getting data returned from previous day at a certain time till the following morning certain time

Tags: sql

I need data to be returned on a daily basis from 17:00 every day until the following morning 08:00.

How do I specify only those times in a query for the data to be returned on a daily basis?

This is the query I have so far:

```sql
DECLARE @yesterday SMALLDATETIME;
SET @yesterday = DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())));

SELECT Desired columns
FROM Desired Table
WHERE Start >= DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @yesterday) and Start < DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @yesterday)
```

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks will keep that in mind. I am new here and still learning the ways here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this give you what you want:

```
-- Today as just a date
declare @today DateTime = convert(date, getdate());
-- Yesterday @ 5pm
declare @start DateTime = dateAdd(hour, -7, @today);
-- Today @ 8am
declare @end DateTime = dateAdd(hour, 8, @today);

SELECT Desired columns
FROM Desired Table
WHERE Start between @start and @end
```

Comment: Thanks, @tappetyclick will give that a go and let you know what the outcome is.

Comment: Thank you very much tappetyclick this was very helpful and worked perfectly.